# Show/Hide UIToolbar on single tap

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitoolbar

I would be really grateful if someone could explain how to show/ Hide UItoolbar and/or UINavigationBar by single taping. eg like in the fullscreen picture gallery. I would like to implement image gallery with controls on the toolbar which would be dissmissed/revealed by tapping once on the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd add a UIGestureRecognizer to the view you're wanting to tap.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTap)];
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap]; 

- (void)didTap
{
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
//Or if you aren't using a nav controller just someToolbar.hidden = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this with a UINavigationBar or UIToolbar (even by themselves, not in a uinavcontroller) is to set custom class properties to the UIImageView (Check "Button" in IB) and use a Touch Down event to run the code (or overlay a transparent button that is the same size as the image with a touch down event):

```
myNavBar.hidden = YES;
myToolbar.hidden = NO;
//etc.
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the UINavigationController's built in toolbar support, you can simply set the controller's "hidesBarsOnTap" to true & let the api take care of it.

```
self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
```

[UINavigationController Reference - Hiding the Navigation Bar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW36)

Answer (score 0):

For the navigation bar it's really easy: `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

The UIToolbar you could animate it out.